# Initialize many string variables

Tags: python, variable-assignment

I'm initializing a lot of string variables as follows:

`a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h = "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""`

You can see that this doesn't look very nice (morever the variables have longer names). Is there some more compact shortcut?

Comment: what are the variables for? Can you use a single list or dictionary instead? Why do you bind all the names at once?

Comment: The variables are attributes (parameters) like id, name, description, ... and many others extracted from a web page. In the `for` cycle some values will be "" and some will be filled and a tuple (a, ... h) will be appended to a list of tuples and variables should be reseted for the next round of for cycle to "" (because the old values shouldn't be mixed)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I will use dictionary as Rik suggests. But he deleted it.

Comment: But I'm not sure if it will be better to have a list of dictionaries instead of list of tuples.

Comment: `tuple(map(some_dict.get, 'abcdefgh'))` to convert to tuple. Or better yet `Attr(**some_dict)` where Attr is a namedtuple.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I'm sorry, I don't exactly understand how you think it. If you have time you could please adjust [this](http://pastebin.com/KwibFUkt) snippet.

Comment: [example](http://ideone.com/LQBY6). You could use [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/library/collections#collections.namedtuple) anywhere you use a tuple but with some niceties.

Comment: Thanks, and is it OK to have a list of dictionaries?

Comment: In Python you could put into a list anything in any combination e.g., `L = [1, None, "abc", object(), {"key": 1.0}, ['nested', 'list],  MyCustomClass(), 'etc',]` it might not be useful but you can.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Definitely more compact:

```
a=b=c=d=e=f=g=h=""
```

Comment: Note this is only makes sense when assigning immutable values.

Comment: @MattJoiner, Why you specify as only when immutable values?

Comment: Because in Python they're all assigned the same reference, and if it's mutable, changing one will change them all.

Answer (score 11):

As an alternative answer to the `a=b=c=...=value` solution try:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h = [""]*8
```

Though if you're doing this, it might make sense to put the variables in a list if they have some relation to each other.

Answer (score 3):

While many of the solutions featured here are cute, I'm going to make the case that the following is the most compact solution you should consider:

```
a = ""
b = ""
c = ""
d = ""
e = ""
f = ""
g = ""
```

These seven lines of code will be read and comprehended *an order of magnitude faster* than any of the other solutions. It is extremely clear that each variable is being initialized to an empty string, and your eyes can quickly comprehend this code and **move on to other more important code**.

And let's be honest, with modern monitors the above code is hardly a waste of screen real estate.

If you find that you need to initialize more than 7 variables then I would suggest *your design needs reconsideration*. Consider replacing these variables with a more dynamic use of a dictionary or list.

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import defaultdict
```

To initialize:

```
attrs = defaultdict(str)
```

To get `'a'` value:

```
print attrs['a'] # -> ''
```

To change it:

```
attrs['a'] = 'abc'
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is about string variables, but to save some lives, remember not to use the same syntax to initialize empty lists:

```
list1 = list2 = []
list1.append('some string!') # This will be added to both list1 and list2
```

Lists are objects and with the above situation, both `list1` and `list2` will have the same reference in memory.

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h = ["" for i in range(8)]
```